# Update datatable header without refreshing the whole application (R, Shiny) dataTableProxy()

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I am trying to make a Shiny app.

(1) I want update data table without refreshing the whole application.
>>> I resolve it with `isolate({})` and `dataTableProxy()`.

(2) I want update the header (column name) without refreshing the whole application, for example (If the user choose in the selectInput 2020. The new colname in the table should update to year: 2020 without refreshing the whole application).

How can I do that?

```
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = 'choice', label = 'choice', choices = c('A', 'B'), selected = 'A'),
  selectInput(inputId = 'country', label = 'country', choices = c('UK', 'USA', 'CANADA'), selected = 'UK'), 
  selectInput(inputId = 'year', label = 'year', choices = c(2020, 2021), selected = 2020),
  uiOutput(outputId = "table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data_a <- data.frame(year = c(rep(2020,6), rep(2021,6)),
                       country = c('UK', 'UK', 'USA', 'USA', 'CANADA','CANADA'),
                       type_a = c('AA', 'BB'),
                       num = sample(10:22, 12))
  
  dt_a <- reactive({
    if (input$choice == 'A'){
      return(data_a %>% filter(year == input$year & country == input$country))
    }
  })
  
  output$rtable_a <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if (input$choice == 'A'){
      DT <- DT::datatable(isolate({dt_a()}), 
                          rownames = FALSE,
                          options = list(processing = FALSE),
                          colnames = c('YEAR', 'COUNTRY', paste('year_a:', input$year), 'NUMBER')
                          )
      return(DT)
    }
  })
  
  proxy_a <- DT::dataTableProxy('rtable_a') 
  observe({
    DT::replaceData(proxy_a, dt_a(), rownames = FALSE)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderUI({
    if (input$choice == 'A'){
      return(DT::dataTableOutput("rtable_a", width = '75%'))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: @RonakShah I modified the data. There is no more of this error : Error in if: argument is of length zero

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the JavaScript library **jQuery contextMenu**. Right-click on the column header and select the year.

[image]

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- c(
  "var choices = {1: '2020', 2: '2021'};",
  "var id = $(table.table().node()).closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
  "$.contextMenu({",
  "  selector: '#' + id + ' th:eq(3)',", 
  "  trigger: 'right',",
  "  autoHide: true,",
  "  items: {",
  "    select: {",
  "      name: 'Select year:',", 
  "      type: 'select',", 
  "      options: choices,", 
  "      selected: '1'",
  "    }",
  "  },",
  "  events: {",
  "    hide: function(opt){",
  "      var $this = this;",
  "      var i = $.contextMenu.getInputValues(opt, $this.data()).select;",
  "      var year = choices[i];",
  "      Shiny.setInputValue('year', year);",
  "      var text = 'year_a: ' + year;",
  "      var $th = opt.$trigger;",
  "      $th.text(text);",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});" 
)


data_a <- data.frame(
  "YEAR"         = c(rep(2020,6), rep(2021,6)),
  "COUNTRY"      = c('UK', 'UK', 'USA', 'USA', 'CANADA','CANADA'),
  "year_a: 2020" = c('AA', 'BB'),
  "NUMBER"       = sample(10:22, 12),
  check.names = FALSE
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.9.2/jquery.contextMenu.min.css"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.9.2/jquery.contextMenu.min.js")
  ),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(data_a, callback = JS(callback))
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  observe({ # selected year
    print(input[["year"]])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## EDIT

With filtering:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- c(
  "Shiny.setInputValue('year', '2020');",
  "var choices = {1: '2020', 2: '2021'};",
  "var id = $(table.table().node()).closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
  "$.contextMenu({",
  "  selector: '#' + id + ' th:eq(3)',", 
  "  trigger: 'right',",
  "  autoHide: true,",
  "  items: {",
  "    select: {",
  "      name: 'Select year:',", 
  "      type: 'select',", 
  "      options: choices,", 
  "      selected: '1'",
  "    }",
  "  },",
  "  events: {",
  "    hide: function(opt){",
  "      var $this = this;",
  "      var i = $.contextMenu.getInputValues(opt, $this.data()).select;",
  "      var year = choices[i];",
  "      Shiny.setInputValue('year', year);",
  "      var text = 'year_a: ' + year;",
  "      var $th = opt.$trigger;",
  "      $th.text(text);",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});" 
)


data_a <- data.frame(
  "YEAR"         = c(rep(2020,6), rep(2021,6)),
  "COUNTRY"      = c('UK', 'UK', 'USA', 'USA', 'CANADA','CANADA'),
  "year_a: 2020" = c('AA', 'BB'),
  "NUMBER"       = sample(10:22, 12),
  check.names = FALSE
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.9.2/jquery.contextMenu.min.css"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.9.2/jquery.contextMenu.min.js")
  ),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(data_a, callback = JS(callback))
  }, server = TRUE)
 
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("dtable")
  
  observeEvent(input[["year"]], { 
    replaceData(proxy, subset(data_a, YEAR == input[["year"]]))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this answer but I really want this colname change depending on the select input without refreshing the whole app. I want it exacly like the rows using the datatable proxy and isolate

Comment: @GreenY This is exactly what my code does. The table is not re-rendered when one selects a year with this method.

Comment: Sorry but we miss understood ^_^.  I don't want the user clic on the colname to change the year. I want it directly from the filter SelectInput when the user filter on 2020 this column must be year:2020 and the  whole table be filtred with 2020 and keep only rows that match with the filter

Comment: @GreenY Ok I think I see now. I think I have a solution but still with "my" select input, the one appearing when one clicks the column name. There's no other way IMHO, cause the proxy does not allow to change the column headers.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much